# 3 items in a row with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Its my first question. I am a secondary operation in an e-shop. I have a problem. When 3 items added in a cart they show 2 in 1st row and 1 in 2nd row. I try to put them in same row.

Item class-> product-inner

The back of three items class-> products.columns-3

I use this code, but nothing happens.

```
ul.products.columns-3{
display: flex;
background-color: white;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
}
div.product-inner{
flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
}
```

Could you help? Thanks

Comment: Your html please

Comment: You should post enough code to reproduce the problem. That makes it easier for us to help you (and it adheres to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Instead of `flex: 0 0 33.3333%`, try this: `flex: 1 0 26%`.

Comment: i edit style.css in a wordpress e-shop. i found classes from inspector (f12). There is no html by me

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul.products.columns-3{
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
div.product-inner{
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products columns-3">
  <div class="product-inner">PRODUCT 1</div>
  <div class="product-inner">PRODUCT 2</div>
  <div class="product-inner">PRODUCT 3</div>
      
</ul>
```

The error is not with the code you provided, it shows three items in a row. 
As you said it is a style.css in a Wordress there is any other style applied bothering you with that.